# Is there an appropriate sequence of parameters to be considered when building a pipeline in Scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**DISCLAIMER:** *I understand this could be considered a subjective type of question, but I'm hoping it is specific enough to not be flagged. Please give it a chance.*

I am doing a GridSearch in scikit-learn on a corpus of 50 books (all kinda average commercially published texts...each ~200 pages of text).

As I began playing with GridSearch, I got to thinking. Surely there must be some sort of 'best practices' for building a pipeline?

Sure, I can include and remove parameters, but I'm really just sorta stabbing around in the dark for the best score.

Possibly, it could make sense to create a smaller, exploratory pipeline using the larger, more effective parameters first. After running this basic pipeline, more parameters that have a smaller effect (in general) could be run next.

For example, say I'm GridSearching a TfidfTransformer.  I am assuming that flipping the `use_idf` switch on or off is going to make a real impact on the scoring, whereas perhaps specifying `alpha=0.000010` versus `alpha=0.000015` won't.

In general, when using a pipeline, is there an alternative to "throw in the kitchen sink" that results in a more cognizant, informative (and possibly faster) experience?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is a gradient based hyperparameter optimization. To enable such a grid search one would have to define a metric on the space of all hyper parameter combinations for the current pipeline.

I don't think this makes sense in your example because of the binary nature of the `use_idf` flag. Lets say your parameter combinations are `(use_idf, alpha)`. Then you would have to do decide what the distance between `(True, 0.00015)` and `(True, 0.00010)` is. In your case it should be smaller than the distance between `(True, 0.00015)`and `(False, 0.00015)`. So

`d((True, 0.00015), (True, 0.00010)) < d((True, 0.00015), (False, 0.00015))`

But what about the distance between `(True, 0.00015)` and `(True, 0.05)`? Will it be still smaller than `d((True, 0.00015), (False, 0.00015))`? I think you get the point.

By choosing the metric you will subjectively influence the search for the best hyper parameters. Probably a random search would be more suitable as suggested in the following paper

```
@article{bergstra2012random,
  title={Random search for hyper-parameter optimization},
  author={Bergstra, James and Bengio, Yoshua},
  journal={The Journal of Machine Learning Research},
  volume={13},
  number={1},
  pages={281--305},
  year={2012},
  publisher={JMLR. org}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[auto-sklearn](http://auto-sklearn.readthedocs.org/en/master/) team is working on finding a way to fully automate the pipeline. It has delivered good results for me so far. Better as what I have got manually with the GridsearchCV.
This can be an answer to your question if you 're happy to use such tool or read their source code.

And at [ML4AAD](http://www.ml4aad.org/algorithm-configuration/) you can find further links to the attempts to solve this problem.